# Convert spaces to dash and lowercase with PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, converters

I've tried a few long methods but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my code

```
<?php print strtolower($blob); ?>
```

Which makes `$blob` lowercase, but additionally I need any spaces in `$blob` to be removed and replaced by a dash (`-`).

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
<?php print (str_replace(' ', '-', $string)strtolower($blob)); ?>
```

Can I accomplish this all in the one line?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, simply pass the return value of `strtolower($blob)` as the third argument of `str_replace` (where you have `$string`).

```
<?php print (str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($blob))); ?>
```

Comment: How to get Glossary A - Z into glossary-a-z?

Answer (score 5):

For a string wrap you can use the dedicated [wordwrap](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function.

> ### str_replace
>
> *[str_replace online documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)*
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> $str = 'Convert spaces to dash and LowerCase with PHP';
>
> echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($str));
> // return: convert-spaces-to-dash-and-lowercase-with-php
> ```

---

> ### wordwrap
>
> *[wordwrap online documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)*
>
> ```
> $str = 'Convert spaces to dash and LowerCase with PHP';
>
> echo wordwrap(strtolower($str), 1, '-', 0);
> // return: convert-spaces-to-dash-and-lowercase-with-php
> ```

[online code: https://3v4l.org/keWGr](https://3v4l.org/X1iVm)

Answer (score 4):

BTW, In WordPress you can use `sanitize_title_with_dashes`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/

Comment: Random, but this is just what I was looking for ty.